# Spring-MVC-Java based Configuration: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker, spring-3

I am using Spring 3 with Java based configuration.

I have a module that exports an Excel sheet to the user (i.e. download a sheet to the user)

I got the following exception at log .... but it exports fine:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been
>   called for this response
>                   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:639)
>                   at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:214)
>                   at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
>                   at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:105)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.processTemplate(FreeMarkerView.java:366)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.doRender(FreeMarkerView.java:283)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerView.renderMergedTemplateModel(FreeMarkerView.java:233)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:167)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>                   at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>                   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>                   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>                   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>                   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>                   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>                   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>                   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
>                   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)

After investigation,I found out that the getOutputStream() method can only be called on a response once.
However I call it every time the user needs to export the sheet as the following:

```
public void exportExcel(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + sheetName + "");


    ByteArrayOutputStream excelFileByteArrayOutputStream =

    excelFileByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
    excelFileByteArrayOutputStream.flush();
    response.flushBuffer();
    excelFileByteArrayOutputStream.close();
  }
```

Freemarker configuration:

```
@Bean
  public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setCache(true);
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setPrefix("");
    freeMarkerViewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    return freeMarkerViewResolver;
  }

  @Bean
  public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/freemarker/");
    Properties settings = new Properties();
    settings.setProperty("number_format", "0.######");
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setFreemarkerSettings(settings);
    Map variables = new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>();

    variables.put("xml_escape", new XmlEscape());
    freeMarkerConfigurer.setFreemarkerVariables(variables);
    return freeMarkerConfigurer;
  }
```

@Controlle ... after the sheet is exported,it never redirects to the home page as I specified:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/smth", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView exportSheet(HttpServletResponse response,
                                                           Bean aBean,
                                                           BindingResult result) throws Exception {

//Some Code
    return new ModelAndView("/home");
  }
```

My WebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class SpringWebApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    // Create the 'root' Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    rootContext.register(WebConfiguration.class);

    // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
    servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

    // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfiguration.class);

    // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
      servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    // Register Spring Security Filter
    DelegatingFilterProxy securityFilter = new DelegatingFilterProxy();
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic securityFilterRegistration =
      servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
    securityFilterRegistration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
  }


}
```

Any ideas how to tickle this issue!

Comment: Can you show your controller code and controller configuration?

Comment: kindly find my updates at my question.

Comment: If your controller is supposed to create an excel sheet why is there freemarker involved? Looks as if after your controller creates the sheet freemarker kicks in and tries to render a (non existing model). How and when is exportExcel() called?